# Is it possible to access an array in html using a scope variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Json array that I want to use in my template file, but to access certain elements of the array I need to use a scope variable. I can do something like this in the controller, but I need to do it in the html file.

Part of my array is shown below:

```
{
fitbit: {
    selected: true,
    user_id: "10537",
    today: [
        {
            date: "Tue, 10 Jan 2017",
            distance: 0,
            steps: 0,
            calories: "0"
        }
    ],
    week: {
        distance: [
            ["0","0","0","0","0"]
        ],
        labels: ["Wed 4th","Thu 5th","Fri 6th","Sat 7th","Sun 8th"],
        steps: [
            ["0","0","0","0","0"]
        ]
    }
},
jawbone: { ... }
}
```

I have a scope variable `$scope.currentDevice` that will change depending on what option the user picks so fitbit, jawbone, etc. 
In the controller I can control which data to access using 
`$scope.wearables[currentDevice]['week']['distance']` so that it gets the correct data using the variable currentDevice.

I need to access `wearables[currentDevice]['week']['distance']` in the template html file but without using ng-repeat and I need to use the scope variable currentDevice to to decide which data to show.

Whenever I try `{{wearables[currentDevice]['week']['distance']}}` in the html file it shows nothing but if I try `{{wearables['fitbit']['week']['distance']}}` it show the value.

Is it possible to show the array data this way and if so how would i do it?

The array data I want to show needs to be displayed in a graph like below where chart-data changes

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="wearables[currentDevice]['week']['distance']" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" ></canvas>
```

if i change it to

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="wearables['fitbit']['week']['distance']" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" ></canvas>
```

it works fine

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: how `currentDevice` gets changed?

Comment: currentDevice is change using a dropdown option - i've got it to change depending on what is chosen from the dropdown

Comment: I'm guessing, my angular is rusty, but this could happen because once you change it, you need to signal to angular that your page needs updating/recompiling. Take a look at $scope.$apply() in conjunction with ng-change.

Comment: What do you initialize currentDevice to?

Answer (score 0):

To display the correct data in the graph, I've used a function. Instead of trying to display data with `wearables[currentDevice]['week']['distance']` i'm using `getDistance(currentDevice)` to return the correct data

the graph code becomes:

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="getDistance(currentDevice)" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" ></canvas>
```

and in the controller the getDistance(device) method is where the data changes depending on what $scope.currentDevice is:

```
$scope.getDistance = function(device) {
    console.log('current device', device );
    return $scope.wearables[device]['week']['distance'];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Depending on what's actually driving your chart, it's possible that the `chart-data` attribute isn't being evaluated properly.  Try changing `chart-data` to `ng-attr-chart-data` and see if that works:

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" ng-attr-chart-data="wearables[currentDevice]['week']['distance']" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" ></canvas>
```

Information about `ngAttr`: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

Comment: He wants not to use ng-repeat.

Comment: I'll update the answer when he provides more context on the template behavior he's looking to achieve

Comment: i want to display `wearables[currentDevice]['week']['distance']` as the chart-data for my bar chart `<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="wearables[currentDevice]['week']['distance']" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" ></canvas`

Comment: Revised the answer, give that a try please.